# Saving user input from website to phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, storage

I am trying to develop a website with HTML, CSS, and Javascript that will let people make their own digital flashcards, but I want to make it so their flashcards are saved to their device's internal storage so that they can be accessed again when that person visits the site again on that same device.

If possible, I'd also like to allow users to export their digital flashcards as a PDF.

Does anyone here know how I might do those things? I have built websites/apps before, but nothing utilizing a device's internal storage or PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save directly to the filesystem on a phone via a website. You can do this in Objective-C/Swift on iOS but I'm not experienced in that area.

An alternative for a website would be to out put and an image (jpg, png etc instead of a PDF) of the flashcard and then the user can "tap & hold" on the image to bring up the "save image" panel to save it to their device (this is how it works on an iPhone).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I'll look into object-C and swift myself, as well as saving the flash cards as images! Thank was very helpful!